# Tried to read a text file line by line. But line is split into two and getting stored on next line

Tags: c#-4.0

I have a text file with special characters as well as normal characters. I am trying to read this file line by line. I have used

`string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("Trial.txt");`

To read it.

I used a break point and tried to find out the values stored in those lines. It broke some of the lines in between without finishing reading it and stored the rest in a new next line. When I checked the records, I found that the breaking occurs only at the point where there are special characters even though it doesn't happen with a particular special character. If the file has a total of 10 lines and if there is 1  line which has this problem, it reads a total of 11 lines. Can any of you guys pleas help me out with this? The text file is in UTF-8 format.

Comment: Do you get the same issue with
string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("Trial.txt").Split('\n');

Comment: Yes, I tried it and have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

The `File.ReadAllLines` method splits the file on carriage return ('\r'), new line ('\n'), or a carriage return followed by a new line (taken from here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2tte0y1.aspx).

Check if the line that is not supposed to be split has either of those characters (judging from your reply to Luke Wyatt you probably have a new line ('\n') on that line at the point where it splits).